# Angular 2 auto date-picker date in form

Tags: javascript, angular, date

I would like to insert date-picker into my form, which shows me automatically today's date without choosing a date. The from below makes you choose the date,  any one can help me please with that..

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="container" for="name">Erän saapumispäivä :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
       <input type="date" class="form-control" id="Entery_Date" 
       [(ngModel)]="addProduct.Entery_Date" name="Entery_Date" #Entery_Date="ngModel">
            <div *ngIf="Entery_Date.errors && (Entery_Date.dirty || Entery_Date.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
                 <div [hidden]="!Entery_Date.errors.required">
                   Erän saapumispäivä on pakollinen!
                  </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi Firas! I see that you're from Finland & that you're a student in school. I assume that English is not your first language, because the code example contains non-English text. Just a friendly tip: Please try to spellcheck & proofread your questions in the future. It'll make them easier for the StackOverflow community to understand. I'll try to correct your first question, so that people will be able to help you out. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a good idea to use material Date Picker (https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview)

It should meet all your requirements

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look to the below example.

```
<input name="dateInput" type="date" ng-model="date"/>
```

Now, in your controller use the below code:

```
var d=new Date();
var year=d.getFullYear();
var month=d.getMonth()+1;
if (month<10){
month="0" + month;
};
var day=d.getDate();
$scope.date=year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
```

Hope this will work :)